# Source for Cremation Specifically Not Jewish

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, funeral-burial-levaya, rishonim, tosfot

A respected Rabbinic figure recently mentioned that one of the Rishonim - maybe Tosfos - writes that אין דרך בני ישראל לשרוף מתיהם: burning a Jew's lifeless body is not the Jewish way. Where is this source?

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/14490754/A_Halachic_View_of_Cremation

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/shiva-and-cremation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’d suggest the quote, albeit not exact, is from Tosafot (Chulin 125b s.v. Yachol):

> בהא דאמרינן בביצה (י.)... דהתם **במת שלם דאין דרך לשורפו** ולנתחו פחות מכזית

Comment: Thank you, I saw the same source, but it didn't seem to be taking about klal Yisroel in particular - unless I didn't read it correctly

Comment: @NJM Hmm, actually didn’t cross my mind that Tos. was *not* speaking of Jews in particular since Rambam ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Defilement_by_a_Corpse.1.13?with=all&lang=bi)) is typically followed in deciding like Rashbi that the laws of purity when imparted by a tent, which is the context of Chulin and Betzah, aren’t applicable to a gentile ([BM 114b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.114b.2?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: I didn't look up the תוספות but from your quotation it sounds like he's referring only to a whole cadaver, which is more limited than the question asked about.

Comment: @msh210 Isn’t that exactly what OP asked about, “a Jew’s lifeless body”?

Comment: Oops, good point, sorry.